# Чем отличаются пользователи в МойСклад?

Tags: moysklad-json-api

entity/employee возвращает ответ с пользователями.
Часть сотрудников содержит поле uid с значением типа логин@аккаунтМС, а часть пользователей не содержит такого значения.
Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Если сотрудник был создан с помощью json api, то у него может не быть uid. Так как для создания достаточно передать только `lastName`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А другие объяснения могут быть?